How can i preload images for LCP?
<img
   src="/assets/img/DM2.webp"
alt="Your Image Alt Text"
                      style={{
                        width: "218px",
                        height: "220px",
                        objectFit: "cover",
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: "60px",
                        right: "1rem",
                        zIndex: 3, // Higher zIndex for the image to be above the second card
                      }}
                    />

I have used react with electron  to making desktop application and facing LCP issue.
I'm using webpack as a bundler for to pack my react app.
